# Unable to Run Multiple Sampler APIs using Ultimate Thread Group in Jmeter

Tags: performance, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have Four Sampler APIs : 3 GET APIs and One Put API and want to do spike test using UltimateThread Group. So i created an ultimate thread Group and added the four APIS under them.I have given split 25 user within different hold time and ramp-up time as per below image. But whenever i am running it is only running the first two API sampler and the last two apis are not running at all.

another issue is that among the two running APIs, only one API is running with 25 threads and other one with only 5 threads ....but its should run 25 threads for each APIs .Kindly let me know whats the issue and as i am new to Jmeter ..trying to resolve the issue but unable to do troubleshoot it.

[APIs Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YawNr.png)

[Ultimate thread Group Set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywVBj.png) : [AGGregate Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEEmP.jpg)  : [TREE REPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdPeq.jpg)

AS YOU CAN SEE THERE FOUR APIS BUT IT HAS EXECUTED ONLY TWO APIS, AMONG THE TWO OF THEM,

ONE HAS 25 THREADS
ONE HAS 5 THREADS
BUT as per my understanding it should run all four APIs with 25 threads for each API sampler...

Answer (score 0):

1. Each user in the Ultimate Thread Group runs for 10 seconds maximum
2. Average Response Times for first 2 Samplers are 12 and 32 seconds correspondingly

The threads shut down times and reasons can be seen in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Assuming above 2 factors the threads are simply being shut down before starting 3rd and further Samplers.

You need to either:

1. Set "Hold load for" to a bigger value, i.e. a couple of minutes
2. Or introduce reasonable response timeouts under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request) so if the response time exceeds acceptable